# Pure mySQL increment loop?

Tags: mysql

Without using PHP or anything. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET var1 = var1 + 1 IF var1 < 5 ELSE var1 = 0 WHERE [WHERE clause]
```

Never really done any IF mySQL things so a little unsure?

So the result would be that the variable would never be higher than 5 and reset to 0 if its at 5 when incremented.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
UPDATE MyTable SET var1 = IF(var1 < 5, var1 + 1, 0) WHERE id = 1;
```

or in this case, simpler, just use the [modulo operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod)

```
UPDATE MyTable SET var1 = (var1 + 1) MOD 6 WHERE id = 1;
```

Edit: Yes, I realize that if the range starts outside of 0..5 the latter one will not work, I just figured the intent was to keep the numbers between 0 and 5 inclusive. If I'm wrong about that, keep to the first one :)

Comment: The modulo-trick is nice, but will fail when there are negative numbers ;)

Comment: What happens, then var1 is more than 6, again the data is set as 1, 2,3,4,5,0, 1, 2, 4, 5,

Comment: @knittl Yes, I realized that after writing it, but let it stay there since I think the intent was to keep the number between 0 and 5 :)

Comment: I used the first one and tested it, does exactly what was needed. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the `if()` function:

```
UPDATE myTable SET var1 = if(var1 < 5, var1 + 1, 0) WHERE [WHERE clause]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET var1 = IF( var1 < 5, var1 + 1, 0 ) WHERE ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is to have two update statements:

```
UPDATE myTable SET var1 = var1 + 1 WHERE [WHERE clause] AND var1 < 5;
UPDATE myTable SET var1 = 0 WHERE [WHERE clause] AND var1 > 5
```

Note that I'm using `var1>5` instead of `var1>=5` in my second example, because columns with value `4` before the first statement will already have been updated to `5` and we don't want those to be reset to zero.